# Solr/SolrNet Help Required

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am having an issue in while querying to solr that when my page size is larger that 75 I got error An
**existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.** 
I think it might be an issue at solr side but nothing is logged in tomcat logs, I am using solr 1.4.1 with solr net

Can any body help me to resolve this particular issue.

here is the stack trace

```
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Query(String q, QueryOptions options)
```

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: Full exception stack trace please.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: stack trace is added

Comment: can you run the same Solr URL from a browser without issue?

Comment: I didn't try the url generated by solrnet, but i can search even 1000 records from solr admin

Comment: Please try the exact URL as generated.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, not an issue at solrnet, actually in that particular search, result is huge and it seems solr is unable to return that much data.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the connection timeout.